# ¿Cómo conectarse a MySQL desde otra PC?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo programando en java y estoy aprendiendo como utilizar mySQL también. Ya puedo conectar una base de datos grabada en mí pc, pero tengo la duda de como conectarla a una base de datos grabada en otra computadora.

Estoy utilizando Netbeans..... como soy nuevo en esto de la programación, agradecería si sus respuestas fueran en un lenguaje sencillo y no tan técnico.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo lo siguiente:

- El equipo A es donde se ejecuta tu motor MySQL.
- El equipo B es donde se ejecuta tu aplicación Java que quiere comunicarse con la base de datos.

Lo primero a considerar es que los equipos (conocidos desde ahora como equipos A y B) pueden comunicarse. Es decir, por lo menos debes comprobar que puedes hacer `ping` a A desde B.

En la cadena de conexión, deberás indicar el nombre del servidor A para conocerlo en la red, o en su defecto la ip para llegar al servidor. El valor sería algo así:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://nombreEquipoA:3306/bdaconectarme";
```

Como puedes ver, `<nombreEquipoA>` puede ser:

- En caso que A y B estén en la misma red LAN o WAN:

  - Hostname del equipo A (p.e. servidor-mysql). Un ejemplo, es el nombre con el que puedes acceder usando `\\servidor-mysql`.
  - IP del equipo A (p.e. 192.168.1.2 o 10.3.50.10)
- En caso que A y B no estén en la misma red LAN o WAN pero puedan comunicarse mediante internet (p.e. servicios en la nube):

  - Hostname del equipo A (p.e. mysqlserver.misubdominio.midominio.com)
  - IP pública que permite la salida del servidor a internet.

Ejemplos:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/bdaconectarme";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://servidor-mysql:3306/bdaconectarme";
//ojo, IP de abajo puesta arbitrariamente por motivos de ejemplo
//no soy responsable del contenido a encontrar en dicha IP
String url = "jdbc:mysql://193.17.49.12:3306/bdaconectarme";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://servidor.enlanube.com:3306/bdaconectarme";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar,  e leído que tengo tengo que el MySQL de wampserver para poder conectarme , eso es cierto?

Comment: @PaulJulio sí, ese también funciona. Lo importante es que el servidor esté corriendo y la conexión entre los dos equipos, A y B, sea exitosa. Es más, si tienes algún cliente MySQL en B y con él puedes conectarte a tu servidor MySQL en A, entonces también podrás conectarte desde tu aplicación Java en B.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda